# Imagemagick - PHP batch convert thumbnails without server stress?

Tags: php, wordpress, imagemagick

I've been using [WPDM](http://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/) to create a file system for a client of mine. Unfortunately WPDM doesn't have any preview functionality for filetypes like psd, ai, pdf, etc so I've been trying to create this functionality myself by using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/).

I'm probably approaching this the wrong way, as I have a major issue with using the code. It only creates the first thumbnail (or two, depending on the psds file size) before it crashes with an Internal Server Error and even one thumbnail makes the site incredibly slow.

```
// Function to create preview images for all files in WPDM package
function create_previews() {
    $file_list = uploaded_files_path();
    $preview_image_path_list=array();

    foreach ($file_list as $file) {
        $imagick = new Imagick();
        $img = wp_get_image_editor($file);
        $imagick->readImage($file);
        $filenamelres = $img->generate_filename('thumb', ABSPATH.'wp-content/uploads/thumbs/', 'png' );

        if ( ! is_wp_error( $imagick ) ) {
            if ( ! file_exists($filenamelres) ) {
                $imagick->setIteratorIndex(0);
                $imagick->thumbnailImage(200, 0);
                $imagick->writeImage($filenamelres);
                $preview_image_path_list[] = $filenamelres;
            } else {}
        } else {
            $preview_image_path_list[] = $filenamelres;
        }

        $imagick->destroy(); 
    }

    return $preview_image_path_list;
}
```

Is there a different route to take here. Could I do the same without stressing the server as much as I'm doing?

Comment: On a system of any non-trivial size, thumbnails are generated in the background, not within the web server process. Switch to cron and use a placeholder thumbnail in the meantime. It's worth finding out what triggered the "Internal Server Error" though - there will be a real PHP error in your logs. I am guessing Apache timed out.

Comment: @halfer I'm not getting any PHP errors in my error_log, only notices that seem totally unrelated. I will definitely check out cron though as it looks like just the kind of thing I was initially looking for, thanks for peeking my interest hehe!

Comment: You're welcome, no probs.

Comment: You could also consider outsourcing it - there are services (like https://cloudconvert.com/) that can do this for you. Often they have beefy servers that are **built** for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment: on a system of any non-trivial size, thumbnails should be generated in the background, not within the web server process. Switch to cron or a job queue, and use a placeholder thumbnail in the meantime.

It's worth finding out what triggered the "Internal Server Error" though - you might need to turn up your error logging to ensure it is recorded.

Comment: I think the reason I didn't get any errors is because I have enabled debug. I'll make some more tests to grasp what's happening before I move over to cron :)

Comment: If you haven't used cron before, be aware of some of the intricacies - for example, all your paths have to be fully qualified (so if you used to use /images/myimage.png, now you have to use /var/app/public/images/myimage.png (or whatever your path from root is)). You also have to be extra diligent on logs - you can't see your "echo's" or "var_dump's" anymore. And php might store the error logs somewhere different for cron than it does for the webserver. Finally, permissions can be different- sometimes cron is run by a different user than the webserver - this could cause issues.

Comment: So cron is a time-based job scheduler, won't that mean that the server would still take heavy hits whenever the cron event takes place?

Comment: Probably not at your stage @michael, but yes eventually. The primary purpose of moving a long-running process to a background task is to ensure the web request returns quickly (and doesn't time out). Once this is done you should keep an eye on server load as your user count increases, and if the load gets very high, it would be time to move the database (or the image processor) to its own server.